# Executing files via Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to write a powershell script to execute all the files in a directory, by alphabetical order. Problem is, I also want to execute each file in the directory. How can I do this last bit?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
gci | ?{$_ -is [io.fileinfo]} | ii
```

You can use the path parameter of Get-ChildItem to chose the directory.

**Update:** Limited selection to only files. Was all items in a directory.

Answer (score 2):

Use get-childitem to find all the items in the directory you want.  You can then convert this list into a list of strings where each string is the name of a file.

Then use the "&" operator to execute each file.

I.E.

```
gci | select name | foreach-object { & $_.tostring() }
```

something like that.

See:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
Get-ChildItem -filter *.exe |
    Invoke-Item
```

You asked for only the programs in a directory.  The IO.FileInfo answer will open word documents as well as run programs.  So will the answer with &.  You don't have to sort alphabetically, because that's how the files come back anyways, but you could put a Sort-Object in the middle if you'd like.

Hope this helps,